# MVC RedirectToAction through ajax jQuery call in knockoutjs is not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I am building a MVC3 web application and I am using knockoutjs. There are two views in the application. SetUpNewCompany and ManageAccount. To Set up a new company the user first enters the account number and clicks search. If the account number already exists the user can click on a button to go to the ManageAccount view. In the SetUpNewCompanyController I redirect using the RedirectToAction method. However, when the Index2 action in ManageAccount is executed the view is not displayed. If I type in the complete URL the view is displayed.

SetUpNewCompanyController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
 public RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToManageAccount(string accountNumber)
 {
        return RedirectToAction("Index2", new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller=
            "ManageAccount", companyId = "7e96b930-a786-44dd-8576-052ce608e38f" }));
 }
```

This above is called by the function below when a button is clicked

```
self.redirectToManageAccount = function () {
        var accountNumber = "7e96b930-a786-44dd-8576-052ce608e38f";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/SetUpNewCompany/RedirectToManageAccount",
            data: { accountNumber: accountNumber },
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
 }
```

ManageAccountController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index2(String companyId)
    {
        var viewModel = new Models.Index();

        List<String> compList = new List<String>();
        compList.Add("MyCompany");

        List<String> usersList = new List<String>();
        usersList.Add("User1");

        viewModel.Users = usersList;
        viewModel.Companies = compList;
        viewModel.CompanyId = companyId;
        viewModel.Role = "Role1";

        return View("ManageAccount",viewModel);
    }
```

The URL that is generated is

```
http://localhost:53897/ManageAccount/Index2?companyId=7e96b930-a786-44dd-8576-
052ce608e38f
```

The console window in Firebug shows

```
GET http://localhost:53897/ManageAccount/Index2?companyId=7e96b930-a786-44dd-8576-
052ce608e38f 200 OK and the spinner keeps spinng
```

Also, how do I get the URL below instead of the one with querystring

```
http://localhost:53897/ManageAccount/Index2/7e96b930-a786-44dd-8576-052ce608e38f
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you use AJAX to call the `RedirectToManageAccount` action method, you are responsible for handling its response yourself and as your `success` handler function is empty, you are effectively ignoring whatever arrives as a response.

If you want to force a redirect from within the AJAX response handler, I suggest

1. Modifying your action method as follows

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult RedirectToManageAccount(string accountNumber)
   {
       var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index2", "ManageAccount", new { companyId = "7e96b930-a786-44dd-8576-052ce608e38f" });
       return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
   }
   ```
2. Updating your AJAX call in this way

   ```
   self.redirectToManageAccount = function () {
     var accountNumber = "7e96b930-a786-44dd-8576-052ce608e38f";
     $.ajax({ type: "POST",
              url: "/SetUpNewCompany/RedirectToManageAccount",
              data: { accountNumber: accountNumber },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (response) {
                  window.location.href = response.Url;
              },
              error: function () {
              }
     });
   }
   ```

As for your second question:

> Also, how do I get the URL below instead of the one with querystring
>   `http://localhost:53897/ManageAccount/Index2/7e96b930-a786-44dd-8576-052ce608e38f`

You just have to define an appropriate route entry for this URL in your `RegisterRoutes()` function:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
                "ManageAccount/Index2/{companyId}",
                new { controller = "ManageAccount",
                      action = "Index2" }                            
);
```

---

**EDIT**: As your AJAX call only serves to call an action method which causes a redirect, you can simplify it in a following way, provided you in this point (on the client side) know the `companyId` already:

```
self.redirectToManageAccount = function () {
    var companyId = "12345";
    window.location.href = '@(Html.ActionUri("Index2", "ManageAccount"))?companyId=' + companyId;
}
```

where I used this extension method

```
public static string ActionUri(this HtmlHelper html, string action, string controller)
{
    return new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext).Action(action, controller);
}
```

Comment: Is there another way to redirect to the ManageAccount/Index2 also i added the route as you suggested but I still got the ?companyId=xxxxx in the URL

Comment: It depends on the specific scenario, really. I updated my answer with one possible simplification of the redirection process. As for the route: are you sure you did not add it __after__ some more general rule?

Comment: i changed the companyid to id and used the default routing route to remove the querystring