# Javascript to execute Action to move file in MVC4

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Upon clicking a button in my MVC's view, the follow javascript function will be executed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidUpload(string) {
        Android.AndroidUpload(string);

        var url = '@Url.Action("TestMove","Functions")';
        $.ajax({ url: url, success: DataRetrieved, type: 'POST', dataType: 'json' });
    }
</script>
```

The AndroidUpload function is a javascript function that runs on my android device and uploads an image into my `~/App_Data/` folder and I wish to move this image to my `~/Content/images/` folder. My Action in my Controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult TestMove()//UploadModel model)//, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> picture)
{     
    string UploadedPath = "~/App_Data/image.jpg";
    string SavePath = "~/Content/images/movedimage.jpg";

    System.IO.File.Move(UploadedPath, SavePath);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The image upload works but the action is never executed. Is this the right way to call it using ajax?

I know my file names etc. are correct so I'm not sure where the issue is.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something...but how does Android play into ASP.NET MVC 4?

Comment: Well the image is coming from an Android device. What I want is the image saved in "~/Content/images/". The android uploads the image but when I'm using `HttpPost` from the Android, the image is always put into the /App_Data/ folder. If it were possible to bypass having to move the file and having it simple uploaded straight to the images folder would be preferable but this is an issue I've spent too long on and am now trying to use this method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** My previous answer, while technically correct was not the best.  Thanks to BASmith for pointing me in the right direction.

**EDIT2:** Added redirect logic from ajax call.

Your action isn't being called because the TestMove method is not a member of this class:

```
public class FunctionsController : Controller
{
}
```

So this can be fixed in one of two ways:

1. Create a `FunctionsController : Controller` class and add the `TestMove` method to it.
2. Change the `"Functions"` parameter in the url string to the name of the controller in which your `TestMove` method currently resides.

Since you are calling your method via ajax, you'll need to deal with the redirect yourself as seen here:
[MVC RedirectToAction through ajax jQuery call in knockoutjs is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005954/mvc-redirecttoaction-through-ajax-jquery-call-in-knockoutjs-is-not-working)

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidUpload(string) {
        Android.AndroidUpload(string);

        var url = '@Url.Action("TestMove","Functions")';
        $.ajax({ url: url, success: function(response){ window.location.href = response.Url; }, type: 'POST', dataType: 'json' });
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult TestMove()//UploadModel model)//, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> picture)
{     
    string UploadedPath = "~/App_Data/image.jpg";
    string SavePath = "~/Content/images/movedimage.jpg";

    System.IO.File.Move(UploadedPath, SavePath);
    var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Home");
    return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
}
```

Comment: public class FunctionsController : Controller
    {

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but yes I know how to make a Controller... and yes my controller is called FunctionsController.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the statement "the action is never executed".  Do you mean the TestMove method is not called or RedirectToAction("Index") is not working?

Comment: I edited the answer to include logic that will fix the ajax redirect issue.