# jQuery ajax call to action and return RedirectToAction

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

### *This question is related to Sitefinity, not simple MVC*

I'm trying to do a post via jQuery to go over to the server, get an Id, and then with the Id retrieved, have the page redirect to another action in another controller.

This always returns a 404, so I need your help.

My Action:

```
public ActionResult SelectedVariation(string mealsAttribute, string portionsAttribute, string product)
{
    Guid productId = new Guid(product);

    CatalogManager catalogManager = CatalogManager.GetManager();
    EcommerceManager ecommerceManager = EcommerceManager.GetManager();

    ProductListWidgetModel model = new ProductListWidgetModel();
    model.Product = catalogManager.GetProduct(productId);
    model.ProductVariations = catalogManager.GetProductVariations(productId).ToList();

    model.SelectedVariation = model.ProductVariations.Where(x => x.Variant.ToLower().Contains(mealsAttribute.ToLower()) && x.Variant.ToLower().Contains(portionsAttribute.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault().Id.ToString();

     return RedirectToAction("Index", "RegisterOrderAccountForm", new { Id = model.SelectedVariation.ToString()});

    //I've tried these ones aswell
    //return Json(new { result = "Redirect", url = Url.Action("Index", "RegisterOrderAccountForm", new { Id = model.SelectedVariation.ToString()})}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    // new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "RegisterOrderAccountForm", action = "Index", Id = model.SelectedVariation.ToString() })), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And my View's JS Code:

```
function GetSelectedVariation() {
    var meals = $('#MealsSelector').val();
    var portions = $('#PortionsSelector').val();

    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("SelectedVariation")', { mealsAttribute: $('#MealsSelector').val(), portionsAttribute: $('#PortionsSelector').val(), product: '@Model.Product.Id' }, function (route) {
        window.location = route;
        //Tried this aswell but to no avail
        //window.location.href = getRootUrl() + route.RouteValues[1].Value + '/' + route.RouteValues[0].Value + '/' + route.RouteValues[2].Value;
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong to always get a 404? One other thing that I've noticed is that on the response the Id value does not come along with the current form.

What is the correct way of having an ajax call to an action, and then redirect to another action/controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: There is no point using ajax when you want to redirect? Just use a form and do a normal submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While indeed most of the answers given are correct, turns out that the issue was with Sitefinity itselft and not really and MVC or jQuery issue.

While Telerik market's Sitefinity as an enterprise-grade MVC CMS, actually Sitefinity's core is built with WebForms.

Unlike MVC, Webforms have a concept of pages, and content is separated between pages so simply calling an action-controller will not work since it doesn't know in which page the action-controller-view are.

In order to achieve this, I ended up storing my ID on a Session variable and I'm just using a simple Redirect after getting the intended page from the pages catalog.

So, here's the correct answer:

This is the action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PlaceOrder()
    {
        string mealsAttribute = Request.Form["MealsSelector"].ToString();
        string portionsAttribute = Request.Form["PortionsSelector"].ToString();
        Guid productId = new Guid(Request.Form["ProductId"].ToString());


        CatalogManager catalogManager = CatalogManager.GetManager();
        EcommerceManager ecommerceManager = EcommerceManager.GetManager();

        ProductListWidgetModel model = new ProductListWidgetModel();
        model.Product = catalogManager.GetProduct(productId);
        model.ProductVariations = catalogManager.GetProductVariations(productId).ToList();

        model.SelectedVariation = model.ProductVariations.Where(x => x.Variant.ToLower().Contains(mealsAttribute.ToLower()) && x.Variant.ToLower().Contains(portionsAttribute.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault().Id.ToString();

        var pages = GetLivePagesNativeAPI();
        var page = pages.Where(x => x.NavigationNode.Title == "Subscribe");

        string action = Url.Action("Index", "RegisterOrderAccountForm", new { Id = model.SelectedVariation.ToString() });
        string destiny = FullyQualifiedApplicationPath + page.FirstOrDefault().UrlName.ToString();

        Session["ProductListWidget_SelectedVariation"] = model.SelectedVariation;

        return Redirect(destiny);
    }
```

And on my View I'm dropping the jQuery Ajax POST and I'm doing a simple form submit:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormSitefinity("PlaceOrder", "VariationSelector", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="bestillbox">
        <input type="hidden" name="ProductId" value="@Model.Product.Id.ToString()" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th id="row">@Html.DropDownList("MealsSelector", @Model.Meals, new { @onchange = "GetPortions();", Name="MealsSelector" })</th>
                <td id="row">Middager</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="row">@Html.DropDownList("PortionsSelector", @Model.Portions, new { @onchange = "GetPrice();", Name="PortionsSelector" })</th>
                <td id="row">Porsjoner</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h6><span id="totalPrice"></span><span>kr/Uka</span></h6>
        <input type="submit" class="bestillbutton" value="BESTILL"/>
    </div>
}
```

Hope this helps anyone going around with Sitefinity and thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Controller.RedirectToAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx)

> Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser
>   to make a GET request to the specified action.

I don't think you're interested to fetch the page HTML.

You should return a JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult SelectedVariation(string mealsAttribute, string portionsAttribute, string product)
{
    return Json(new { url = Url.Action("RegisterOrderAccountForm", new { id = "1"}) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

since I am returning a new json object with an attribute url your ajax call should be:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("SelectedVariation")', { mealsAttribute: meals, portionsAttribute: portions, product: product }, function (route) {
    window.location = route.url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Refer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12006362/2632619

Action should return url like below format:

```
public ActionResult SelectedVariation(string mealsAttribute, string portionsAttribute, string product)
{
    Guid productId = new Guid(product);

    CatalogManager catalogManager = CatalogManager.GetManager();
    EcommerceManager ecommerceManager = EcommerceManager.GetManager();

    ProductListWidgetModel model = new ProductListWidgetModel();
    model.Product = catalogManager.GetProduct(productId);
    model.ProductVariations = catalogManager.GetProductVariations(productId).ToList();

    model.SelectedVariation = model.ProductVariations.Where(x => x.Variant.ToLower().Contains(mealsAttribute.ToLower()) && x.Variant.ToLower().Contains(portionsAttribute.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault().Id.ToString();
    // return RedirectToAction("Index", "RegisterOrderAccountForm", new { Id = model.SelectedVariation.ToString()});

    var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "RegisterOrderAccountForm", new { Id = model.SelectedVariation.ToString()});
    return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });

}
```

Then your ajax call should redirect like below:

```
 $.getJSON('@Url.Action("SelectedVariation")', { mealsAttribute: $('#MealsSelector').val(), portionsAttribute: $('#PortionsSelector').val(), product: '@Model.Product.Id' }, function (route) {
        window.location = route.Url;;        
    });
```

Comment: nope, that doesn't work. Had tried it before. Maybe that's a problem with Sitefinity CMS rather than with the code itself..