# event.preventDefault() and redirect asp mvc/jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What am trying to do is to post on form submit to a action and catch response and that works fine.Problem is when RedirectToAction gets called, it just stays on that same view(it doesn't redirect),or in case model is not valid, it doesn't show model validation. So i guess the problem is with url, but how can I correct it?

## jQuery

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);

  var formURL = form.attr("action");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: formURL,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
      if (response !== null && response.success == false) {
        alert(response.responseText);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

## c# asp mvc

```
public ActionResult Add(SomeModel model) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    if (true) {
      return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Some error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
  }
  //gets called but it doesn't show validation.
  return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Details(int id) {
  //gets called but it doesn't show the view.
  return view(model);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005954/mvc-redirecttoaction-through-ajax-jquery-call-in-knockoutjs-is-not-working

Comment: First; I have no idea how redirecttoaction ever gets called, unless something changed in C# so you can return multiple times in a function. If everything worked fine you should see the view content in the alert. Not sure you understand the concept of ajax. You'd see the views if you just remove the javascript and submit the form.

Comment: Yea, i would see the views if i remove the form on submit function, but then Json result would just show in another window. My idea was to catch it with that javascript function and display it on alert.

Comment: But the real problem is with event.preventDefault() , if that gets called all other redirects after that just stop working.If i remove it from on submit function i get two same records(because am posting again on submit) and redirects from other actions are working normally.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. Ajax calls **never** redirect. Do not use ajax (which in your case makes no sense anyway). Make a normal submit.

Comment: All right, thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're posting your form with an Ajax POST and your in your success function you have alert(response.responseText), you are NOT going to receive a View.

What you need to do is in success function, take the response from Details action and place it inside an HTML element on the page. Like below:

```
        success: function (response) {
            $("#div").html(response);
        }
```

On another note, since you're not using a standard FORM and your posting with JavaScript, you wont get built in validation the models provide.